# Extract nodes and relationships using only attribute values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to extract the nodes and their relationships based on the value of the attribute value of the node.

---

**Background and Progress so far:**

I am trying to find the named entities in a given sentence using Stanford CoreNLP RegexNER which is giving me the named entities.

I am giving an sentence like: `I want to travel by my own car from Pune to Bangalore what is my reimbursement`

So I am getting the named entities:

- `Pune` - LOCATION
- `Bangalore` - LOCATION
- `own car` - VehicleType

I have constructed a graph in Neo4J statically as follows:

[image]

---

**The issue:**

So given a sentence via a REST API: `I want to travel by my own car from Pune to Bangalore what is my reimbursement`

I need to construct a dynamic cypher query which will traverse the graph and give me the node relationships and the node values.

I have tried using the [apoc.path.expandConfig](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_with_config) stored procedure.

This is the cypher query which I am writing assuming I get the named entities out of Stanford CoreNLP, but it gives me wrong output.

```
MATCH (e1), (e2)
WHERE e1.name in ['Bangalore', 'Pune'] AND e2.name = 'OwnCar' 
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(e1, { terminatorNodes: [e2], limit: 5  }) YIELD path
WITH [relation in relationships(path) | type(relation)] as rel, nodes(path) as nodes
RETURN { Relations: rel, Nodes: nodes } as results
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

I want to traverse the graph and get the `reimbursement value` for the following sentence entered.

[image]

This is the direction of traversal which is needed.

The final output must be `Rs8`.

---

**The main issue is to query the graph given only the attribute values minus the relationships, as its not possible to get the exact relationships on how to traverse from Stanford CoreNLP.**

I maybe totally wrong in approaching this problem, I am at a total loss of options, but I need to traverse the graph somehow and get the result.

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info to know what you want here. You've provided the graphical output but not the table output. You need to tell us what the output is and why it isn't correct for your use case. Please let us know what the expected output should be that you want the query to return. Also you should be using labels in your query and have indexes in place to support fast lookup of your starting nodes.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I have updated the question for the direction of traversal

Comment: @InverseFalcon in short we are trying to build a QnA type of system, where any questions can be looked up into Neo4J, my approach may be completely wrong here, but I am open to listen for suggestions